# Keras lambda layer for l2 norm

Tags: python, keras

I just want to implement a custom layer for taking the l2 norm of two vectors (of matching dimensions of course) which were output by 2 different models in keras. I'm using the functional API method of writing keras functions, so I have stuff like:

```
    inp1 = Input(someshape)
    X = Conv2D(someargs)(inp1)
    ...
    ...
    out1 = Dense(128)(X)

    inp2 = Input(someshape)
    Y = Conv2D(someargs)(inp2)
    ...
    ...
    out2 = Dense(128)(Y)
```

Then I want to take the l2 norm of the distance between out1 and out2 and feed it further into another network, so I have a lambda layer like:

```
    l2dist = keras.layers.Lambda(l2dist)(out1,out2)
```

Where l2dist is the function defined as:

```
    def l2dist(x,y):
        return K.sqrt(K.sum((x-y)**2))
```

But I get an error for the l2dist =... line saying:

```
    TypeError: __call__() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
```

I clearly only put 2 arguments, out1 and out2, why does python think I'm giving 3 arguments?
I've tried this with a lambda function like:

```
    l2dist = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x,y: K.sqrt(K.sum((x-y)**2)))(out1,out2)
```

But I get the same error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I discovered that the Lambda layer in keras can only accept one argument as input, so I have to input the lambda function as a function on a list and pass the two tensors in as a list. I also realized that I can't use the l2 norm since that only gives me 1 number to run the final layers on, I have to use a different distance function that can give an element wise distance rather than a Euclidean distance between two vectors. I'm now using the chi-squared distance, so my code looks like this and it runs (but it's giving me nan as a loss, but that's a different issue I guess. At least it runs):

```
    chisqdist = keras.layers.Lambda(lambda x: (x[0]-x[1])**2/(x[0]+x[1]))([out1,out2])
```

Comment: Nan losses may be due to division by zero in the model. Also, I got Nan losses every time I tried to use `K.sqrt` in my loss, I couldn't figure out why...

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it's because the division by x[0]+x[1] will result int division by zero whenever both of those values are 0 (the numerator is also 0 in that case, but 0/0 is still nan). Those values are 0 quite frequently if I use relu activation function. Things work if I switch to sigmoid activations (but then training gets stuck easily) so I just added a small epsilon to the denominator and things seem to be working.

Comment: @enumaris can you specify how you would add a small epsilon to the denominator?

Comment: @armstrongsubero This was a long time ago, but I believe I just added it by fiat. `lambda x: (x[0]-x[1])**2/(x[0]+x[1]+epsilon)` where `epsilon` is just some parameter I set to like `1e-8` or something. The point is just when both `x[0]` and `x[1]` are `0` then you get `0` instead of a `nan` and `epsilon` has to be small enough that it doesn't affect the division normally.